# Getting a json object from HttpServletResponse

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I am sending a json object via ajax call.
When I try to print the json's values I am getting nulls.

What am I doing wrong?

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.getWriter().write("[{\"PARENT\":\"2\",\"VAL\":\"X7280\"},{\"PARENT\":\"2\",\"VAL\":\"X8338\"}]");
}
```

javascript:

```
    function handleIt()      {              
        var url = "myservlet";
        var parameters = "method=method";
        http.open("POST", url, true);        

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4) {                      
            var ddl3 = http.responseText;                           

            for(var key in ddl3){                   
                    var id = ddl3[key].PARENT;
                    var lbl = ddl3[key].VAL;

                    alert (lbl);

         }
      }
  }
    http.send(parameters);
}
```

Comment: Try ddl3 = JSON.parse(http.responseText);

Comment: Yes, your `http.responseText` is a text, not a JSON

Comment: add an answer and i'll accept